# Declaring an instance of a composite type without initializing all the fields

Tags: struct, types, julia

So I am trying to create an instance of a structure:

```
struct keypoint
    x
    y
    scale
    angle
    Vector{Any}(VecLength)
end
```

Now I know the values of all the fields except the last one. I need to initialize the instance of the structure with the known values but for the last field I have to call another function where the data to be generated and then stored in the last field of the instance. Is there a way to get this done in Julia?

I am referring to the tutorials [here](http://bogumilkaminski.pl/files/julia_express_v0.6.2.pdf) and [here](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/julia/) but I guess in both places all the fields of the instance have been initialized at one go.

Thanks!

Comment: [Incomplete Initialization](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/constructors/#Incomplete-Initialization-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mutable struct keypoint
    x
    y
    scale
    angle
    keypoint(x,y,scale) = new(x,y,scale)
end
a = keypoint(1,1.0,2.0) # keypoint(1, 1.0, 2.0, #undef)
```

Notice that if you then try to access `a.angle` you get

```
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(::Any, ::Symbol) at .\sysimg.jl:18
```

so by leaving it off you get an `undef` in there that errors upon access. But you can then set it later.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris!